# SOQL Query on FieldPermissions

Tags: soql, profile, field-permissions

I want to list out Read and Write permissions for a few fields on an object from a profile. I have a profile named Master_Junior and under the profile I want to find out all the field permissions from Account object. I've constructed this query for it

```
SELECT SObjectType, Field, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit FROM FieldPermissions 
  WHERE SObjectType = 'Account' AND 
        Field IN('Name','ShippingStreet','ShippingCity') AND
        Parent.Profile.Name  = 'Master_Junior'
```

But no data gets exported when I execute it. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is that per [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm) the SObjectType prefixes the field name in the `Field` field. So this returns a row:

```
select SObjectType, Field, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit
from FieldPermissions
where SObjectType = 'Account'
and Field in ('Account.Phone')
and Parent.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'
```

And a second thing is that there is an `Account.ShippingAddress` field row, but presumably because an address is a composite, there are not individual rows for Street, City etc.

Comment: This really helps. Thank you. But for some reason it doesn't pick up all the fields. It's exporting result for only a few specific fields. I'm not sure what the pattern is here

Comment: Hi @Niklaus, if you drop the `and Field in` term you will see what fields are available. Your profile may be granting access to very few of them.

Comment: Hi @keith I have the access but I don't see some fields like RecordTypeIDn on many objects. Status field on Case. Can't be random

Comment: Hi @Niklaus, I can imagine `RecordTypeId` being always available as that is part of the internal plumbing. Can't explain Status field on Case. Post a new question if you've narrowed it down to a specific fields providing that detail.